# Load mobile app localization resources dynamically from cloud cms

Tags: react-native, localization, contentful

I have react-native cross platform mobile app. I want to move its localization resources to some online service, so I can update texts with out updating the whole app.

There is a lot of different cloud based cms systems available, but what would be best fit for managing app localizations?

So far I have tried to evaluate Contentful cms, they have javascritp lib etc. But I do not think their systems, model structures, suits very well for mobile app licalization resource storage?

Comment: I would like to know good options to Contentful too :)

Answer (score 1):

Contentful is a great way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Check out this [Dynamic Microcopy article](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/dynamic-microcopy/). Essentially you create 2 content types: a `Resource` content type with a `Key` field and a `Value` field (both short text) and a `Resource Set` content type with a `Name` short text field and a `Resources` multi-reference field with a validation to accept only `Resource` entries

[image: resource set validation]